# Mypy type confusion with Union of Callable

Tags: python, union, mypy, callable

I'm relatively new to Python type hinting and mypy and was wondering why the following code fails mypy verification.

```python
from typing import Callable, Union

class A:
    a: int = 1

class B:
    b: int = 1

def foo(cb: Union[Callable[[A], None], Callable[[B], None]]):
    a = A()
    cb(a)

def bar(a: A) -> None:
    print(a)

foo(bar)
```

This fails with the following message

```
test.py:11: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "A"; expected "B"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

From reading this, I would assume that the argument `cb` can either take a `Callable[[A], None]` or a `Callable[[B], None]` but it seems that's not the case? Can someone explain what's going on here? Is this a mypy thing and an implementation quirk, are my assumptions wrong or is this somehow expected?

Thanks!

Comment: `foo` can take one or the other. But statically speaking, `mypy` cannot tell if `cb` can take an `A` as its argument or not: that depends on *runtime* behavior.

Comment: Analyze the generic case: Let's say foo is passed a callable that receives B so `cb(a)` is not allowed, that's the error mypy catches.

Comment: I assumed mypy would be able to statically make sense out of it, since it does with much more complex stuff and assumed that it would only report these kinds of errors if that code path was actually reachable. I guess this is not validly type hinted then, even though such a code path where a callable is passed to `foo` which takes an argument of type `B` doesn't exist? What would be the best way to type hint such a scenario, where it's guaranteed by program logic that an incorrect callback will never be called? Should some kind of explicit checks be added?

Comment: You'll have to give a clearer example of why you want to accept a union type as the argument. Right now, `foo` doesn't try to make any use of `cb` as something that takes a `B` as an argument, so why accept such a function as an argument?

Comment: It's not sufficient for there to be *a* code path where `cb(a)` type checks: it has to be true for *all* code paths.

Comment: This is basically a striped down example. In reality, I have another argument in `foo` which dictates the type of argument `cb` will be called with. `foo` is used in both scenarios, where it's passed a `Callable[[A], None]` and later a `Callable[[B], None]`. The argument which dictates if the `Callable` is called with a type `A` or type `B` is constant and never changes during execution. It's guarded by an if statement of the third argument known before runtime. This way, the `Callable` can never be called with an incorrect type, assuming the third argument which dictates the type is correct.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` only knows what you told it about `cb`: either it is a function that takes an `A` value as an argument, or it is a function that takes a `B` values as an argument. It is *not* a function that can take either an `A` or a `B`.

Typed as it is, you can't really call `cb` at all, because you don't know what type it accepts. (You know it's one of two, but not *which* one.)

---

Update: to be precise, as pointed out by @joel, you can't call it with a value that is *only* an instance of `A` or an instance of `B`. You *could* call it with a value that is an instance of *both*. For example, the following type checks

```
class C(A, B):
    pass

def foo(cb: Union[Callable[[A], None], Callable[[B], None]]):
    c = C()
    cb(c)
```

because `c` satisfies either condition.

Comment: i'm going to nitpick (sorry, in the mood), and point out that you can call it with a subclass of `A` _and_ `B`